# How to write following query in mysql using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**My Aim:**Insert the Qty into Db of each I_Code as per each I_Name.

Expected Output

```
      stock_color
I_Code   I_Qty   I_Name
M1        50      PYC
M2        50      PYC
M1        25      P285C
M3        70      P285C
M4        15      P285C
```

PHP+Mysql

```
$ink={M1,M2,M1,M3,M4};
$Qty={50,50,25,70,15};
$ink_name={PYC,P285C};

for($j=0;$j<count($ink_name);$j++)
{
         $sql[] = "insert into stock_color (I_Code,I_Qty,I_Name) values ('$ink[$j]','$Qty[$j]','$ink_name[$j]')"
                foreach ($sql as $query) {
                         mysqli_query($query,$con);
                     }          
}
```

Now,Code is working but with wrong results.Please help me out.Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to swap the parameters in your `mysqli_query`. And the foreach-loop should not be inside the for-loop.

Comment: In general, never execute a query inside a loop. However, when using parametrised queries in pdo (which is what you should be doing) the opposite is true!

Comment: Should be `mysqli_query($con,$query);`

Comment: @Strawberry I wan't aware of Parametrised queries in pdo, I will look into that.

Comment: @Akshay Its, mysqli_query($query,$con), because for mysqli_query($con,$query); its giving error.

Comment: @MrDarkLynx Already tried to swap the parameters but showing errors.Is there any other alternative for not using for loop.

Answer (score 0):

please try this code

```
<?php
 $ink=array('M1','M2','M1','M3','M4');
 $Qty=array(50,50,25,70,15);
 $ink_name=array('PYC','PYC','P285C','P285C','P285C');

 for($j=0;$j<count($ink_name);$j++)
  {
     //$sql .= "insert into stock_color (I_Code,I_Qty,I_Name) values ('$ink[$j]','$Qty[$j]','$ink_name[$j]')";
    if($j==0){
        $sql .= " ('$ink[$j]','$Qty[$j]','$ink_name[$j]')";
    } else {
        $sql .= ", ('$ink[$j]','$Qty[$j]','$ink_name[$j]')";
    }

   }
   echo $final_query = "insert into stock_color (I_Code,I_Qty,I_Name) values " .$sql;
?>
```

Comment: But, there might be so many entries, I can't write manually for each one.

Comment: in this case need to other solution . ok try to give solution